# Pass variables from Twig form

Tags: symfony, controller, twig

I am a newbie in Symfony2. My problem is: I would like to pass values from Twig form to database.
Controller:

```
public function createAction()

{
    $product = new Product();
    $product->setName('name');
    $product->setPrice('price');
    $product->setDescription('description');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($product);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response('Izveidots produkts id '.$product->getId());
}
```

I would like to use values from the form instead of using constant ones ('name', 'price'). The view:

```
<form action="{{ path('blogger_blog_create') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    {{ form_row(form.name)}} 
    {{ form_row(form.price) }}
    {{ form_row(form.description) }}

    {{ form_rest(form) }}

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I am trying to figure it out for a couple of hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all information you need in the [official symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/forms.html). The simplest example:

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
    }
}
```